# Can i pass array of options to compare in an if statement

Tags: laravel, if-statement

I need to check is a user from a few countries in my laravel project.

Obviously I can do this

```
if($user->country == 'Ireland' || $user->country == 'England')
```

Is there a way to clean this up?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
in_array($user->country, ['Ireland', 'England', 'Scotland']);
```